# Access control is not enabled for the database - mongodb

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I am getting this issue. tried many steps but same problem . while trying to fire any queries its giving same issue.

Comment: MongoDB recommended that you have to enable access control after MongoDB installation. Follow this https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/enable-authentication/ to solve your problem.

Comment: This question keeps getting pointed to that page but I dont think it answers the question